# Resources to understand the Higgs boson

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking

I have to do a presentation about the Higgs boson, covering topics such as the problems with the standard model without Higgs, particle masses not being compatible with gauge symmetry and how it is solved using spontaneous symmetry breaking - and I have to discuss the Higgs mechanism. Moreover, I have to discuss the experimental  side of it, such as the collider experiments and how it was found in 2012.

The problem is that I don’t have a background in particle physics or QFT and I was wondering from where to start like if someone could provide me with some resources and material I will be very grateful.

Comment: try the CERN site for example https://home.cern/news/news/physics/basics-higgs-boson

Comment: It is not necessary to have background in QFT or particle physics - or anything quantum to begin with. Most of the rough contours can already be seen in the classical unification model. I am sure if you google classical electroweak unification / goldstone theorem you will find plenty of material available.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend you the book "Modern Particle Physics" by Mark Thomson. It is a good book with a healthy mix of experiments and theory, and clearly demonstrates the problem of masses (of the gauge bosons and elementary particles) and the solving with the Higgs field. Particularly Ch. 17 should (hopefully) answer at least some questions.

One should calculate some time to get a feeling for things, though..